# Copiar coluna JTable para Área de Transferência?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, área-de-transferência

Tenho aqui um modelo de tabela com 4 colunas e várias linhas preenchidas que pego no banco de dados. Eu gostaria de criar um botão Action que copie as colunas 2 e 3 de uma vez para a área de transferência, e assim conseguir colar, por exemplo, num Excel ou outros lugares. É possível?

Segue o modelo da Jtable que estou usando.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MinhaTabelaEditavel extends AbstractTableModel {
private ArrayList linhas = null;
private String[] colunas = null;

public MinhaTabelaEditavel (ArrayList lin, String[] col){
    setLinhas(lin);
    setColunas(col);    
}

public ArrayList getLinhas() {
    return linhas;
}

public void setLinhas(ArrayList dados) {
    this.linhas = dados;
}

public String[] getColunas() {
    return colunas;
}

public void setColunas(String[] nome) {
    this.colunas = nome;
}

public int getColumnCount(){
    return colunas.length;
}

public int getRowCount (){
    return linhas.size();
}

public String getColumnName (int numCol){
    return colunas[numCol];
}

public Object getValueAt (int numLin, int numCol){
    Object[] linha = (Object[])getLinhas().get(numLin);
    return linha[numCol];
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
return true;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** da sua tabela com alguns dados. Esse código não é executável.

Answer (score 2):

Conforme [**esta resposta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24704037/5524514) no SOEn, você precisará converter o texto para um tipo de texto que é possível copiar para a área de transferência, depois apenas enviar o texto normalmente, através da classe [`Clipboard`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html), conforme abaixo:

```
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(<texto a ser copiado>);
Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);
```

No seu caso, bastaria recuperar o texto a ser copiado das colunas desejadas  utlizando o método `getValueAt()` e passando para o `StringSelection`.

Veja um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]